# How to Change the Text Selection Toolbar color which comes when we copy a text?

Tags: android, textview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-theme

I am developing an application and i set "android:textIsSelectable" for the TextViews.

But my material theme is not matching with the TextSelection appBar. Is there a way by which i can change the color of that appBar ??

Attached the Image Below Check it :-

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assuming you use the `appcompat-v7` library add these to your theme:¨

```
<!-- this makes sure the action mode is painted over not above the action bar -->
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
<item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/myapp_action_mode_background</item>
```

Now I wasn't able to style the insides of the action mode (text color, icon colors) so hopefully you won't need to.

Note: If you don't use the support library prepend those style item names with `android:`. These will work above API 11+.

**EDIT**

For an action mode background with a stroke create a new drawable and update the reference. The drawable could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:top="-2dp" android:left="-2dp" android:right="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/primary_dark"/>
      <stroke android:color="@color/accent" android:width="2dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: The color of text and menu items will most likely be the same as in your standard app bar.

Comment: Glad I could help, If you wanted to change the images or title style look through the [platform's themes.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) and search for "actionMode".

Comment: But after implementing this the whole Action Mode is in blue color which was set by me, is there anyway that i can get an yellow underline under the action Mode, as show in figure.      i.e i need the action same as in the figure except the black need to be blue

Comment: and also is here anyway that i can add a share button in action mode ??

Comment: See the updated answer. With the share button I can't help you :(

Comment: Works Perfectly thanks for the help. See if you can get any resources to add share button also. and once again thanks

Comment: when using translucent status bar that becomes black, is there a way to style status bar when action bar is shown?

Comment: You need to use [`ScrimInsetsFrameLayout`](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java). Copy the class to your project and wrap your curent activity layout in it. You'll also need [`ScrimInsetsView` definition from `attrs.xml`](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml). In your layout don't forget to set the `app:insetForeground` attribute to a color of your choice and `android:fitsSystemWindows` to `true`.

Answer (score 5):

In your resources styles.xml: `"android:textColorHighlight"`

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/yellow</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

You can put in whatever color you choose and whatever parent theme you are using.

Comment: I think the OP wanted to color the action mode, not the text selection.

Comment: But maybe if he didn't need to change the whole background but just the colored underline... Perhaps it inherits from `android:textColorHighlight` or at least `colorAccent`...

Comment: Yeah i know what you are talking about the highlight yellow color right. I set it by myself. Thanks for the reply