# How can I change the Android text selection mode theme?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-theme, android-actionmode

I don't really know what the visual elements are called, I called them *text selection mode indicators*. Some screenshots, taken from Chrome and Opera on the same android device.

The first is the current theme of the text selection mode indicators (from Chrome, same as my app):
[image: Current text selection mode indicators]

And the desired theme (Opera):

[image: Desired text selection mode indicators]

One can see how, within the desired theme, they are large enough to not be useless to anyone not using a stylus.

Any keywords that I can use in researching this myself are more than welcome! :)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277676/how-to-change-the-text-selection-toolbar-color-which-comes-when-we-copy-a-text

Answer (score 2):

```
it is called text cursor drawable 
you can change it easily using a drawable

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/rt1"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_tuy"
       .
       .
/>
```