# Android - edittext - no textselection handles are shown and no sharing option

Tags: android, android-layout, copy-paste

On an App screen I have a number of EditText views. My app is built using the Material Design (AppCompactActivity, etc).

While showing an EditText field, with a long press I try to select a number of words in the text. This allows me to copy or share that text. Selecting more than 1 word seems not possible.

Since the migration to Material Design I see 2 things:

1 - After a long press there are no selection handles shown. So, on the place of the question marks I expected inverse waterdrops. These are the handles you normally use to change the particular selection.

Question: why are these reverse eyedrops gone? I do see them when selecting text in e.g. a webview.

Yes, I use 'android:textIsSelectable="true"'. Below you see the EditText layout.

[image]

2 - The "sharing" option for the selected text is not available. Why?

[image]

What is the EditText field?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/geocache_info_hint"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:lines="4"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:text=""/>
```

Upon selection of a text (in this case 1 word) what I also see is that an extra bar 'tekstselectie' (=textselection) is put on top of the screen. That's also a difference since Android 4.

[image]

** Solution **

In my theme I had a line that caused the problem of not showing any text selection handles:

```
<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/window_background</item>
```

The @color/window_background was chosen as white.

Comment: Are you building with appcompat-v7 version 23.1.1?

Comment: I researched the problem and didn't find anything.  Couldn't reproduce on any of my devices.  I don't know if using the latest appcompat version would help.

Comment: I upgraded everything to 23.1.0. Alas, no change. 
Why is this working for webview and not for edittext?

Comment: Can you try adding to edittext  android:imeOptions="actionSend" ? Also, what is your theme parent?

Comment: Adding the imeOptions doesn't help. The theme parent is: <style name="Base.Theme.Xyz" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">. In Android 4 (I used for 1 year) I had no such issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Upd2:**

Also, as **tjm1706** figured out, it's important to carefully review the Theme property. In this case, the key was to remove `<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/window_background</item>`

**Upd1:**

1. To avoid this "double-toolbar" on editing, add this to your Theme's style:

   ```
   <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
   <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/myapp_action_mode_background</item>
   ```

   taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28278946/1658267)
2. To add Share (or any other button) - you need to set on your `EditText` `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback`:

   Check out this question: [Custom cut/copy action bar for EditText that shows text selection handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995439/custom-cut-copy-action-bar-for-edittext-that-shows-text-selection-handles) - it contains detailed example.

**Original:**

Try to **remove**: `android:textIsSelectable="true"`. It's not possible to type with it. And if you don't need `EditText` to be editable - probably, simple `TextView` suits you better.

Without it, your `EditText` works fine for me:

[image]

Comment: Alas, it doesn't help. A difference with your demo is that an extra copy-paste bar is put on top of the screen.

Comment: @tjm1706 does it put extra copy-paste bar even on Android M? (this floating bubble thing with share/copy in the gif is standard in M)

Comment: I updated the 'question' with what I see now. Sufficient info?

Comment: @tjm1706 ok, now I see - then it's an issue with a way you work with a  toolbar. I'll try to repro it and update the answer.  (Though, the EditText you posted, doesn't work with android:textIsSelectable="true" at all)

Comment: @tjm1706 I believe, this is the solution you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277676/how-to-change-the-text-selection-toolbar-color-which-comes-when-we-copy-a-text

Comment: Well, I found it ... Thanks to you. You gave the right direction. 
The extra textselection bar, .... I don't mind. BUT ... when looking in the theme I saw the following line... and removed this line. So, when you add this to your answer, you get the bonus of +50. 
So, this is wrong. It gives a white background ... not showing the handles. 
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/window_background</item>

Comment: @tjm1706 interesting fact, though: it in Android M it works even with `android:popupBackground` (but the drops have square background around) :-) Great, that you've figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Add android:textIsSelectable in xml.